# FMDBで前方一致または後方一致検索を行う

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

`FMDB`を使って前方一致や後方一致検索を行おうとしているのですが、以下のようなSQL文を書くと、「`data argument not used by format string`」という警告が出てきて実際にうまく値を取ってこれません。（下記のSQL文は前方一致検索を行っているつもりです）

```
NSString *SQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Animals WHERE name LIKE '%%@'", animalName];
```

FMDBを使って前方一致または後方一致検索を行うにはどのように書けばいいでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。
すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `%` が特殊な意味を持っていますので、SQL の `%` として使う場合はエスケープする必要があります。`LIKE '%%%@'` ただ、こちらでは試すことができないので間違っていたましたらごめんなさい。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご回答いただいた内容の LIKE '%%%@'で試してみたのですが、前方一致で検索ができませんでした。
　動物 | 動物 | 動物：イヌ | 動物：ネコ　とそれぞれ4つのカラムがあるとすると、今は最初の2つの動物しか取得できない状況です。。。

Comment: 日本語検索を行っていたので、日本語の前後に%を付けることで解決できました！回答がとても参考になりました。誠にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blog.ryuraku.com/2011/09/02/iphoneipadsqlitelike/

上記のサイトに日本語で検索をするには日本語の前後に%を付けると書いていたので、以下のようにすると検索を行うことができました。

```
NSString *animalNameForPatternMatching = @"%動物%";
NSString *SQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Animals WHERE name LIKE '%%%@'", animalNameForPatternMatching];
```

Comment: 「日本語の前後に%を付ける」とはサイトを見ても書いていないように思います。`LIKE`の`%`は「0文字以上の任意の文字列」なので、前後に`%`を付けると質問の挙動とは変わってしまいます。`LIKE ?`に`%%%@`で書式化した文字列をバインドするのが一番いいような…。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。あまり上記のやり方はよくないのですね。今の所上記のやり方でうまくいっているのですが、ご提示のLIKE ? の方を試してみたいと思います。